# Trying to get duplicates in Left Join in Access 2003 SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm actually trying to keep duplicates so I can list them multiple times on a report. I have items that apply to more than one brand, I use a series of checkboxes for each record to indicate whether it applies to that brand or not:

```
Item1 brand x  
Item2 brand y,z  
Item3 brand y
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to select the records in a query so I can run a report grouped by brand, showing duplicate wherever they occur:

```
Item1 x  
Item2 y  
Item2 z  
Item3 y
```

Everything I can find is about getting rid of duplicates. Open to all solutions. Help is greatly appreciated. (I've got some code experience, but so far SQL and Access in general are self-taught.)

Comment: What does your table structure look like?

Comment: The brands are set as yes/no values across 9 or so columns in the main table. The brands table has the full name of the brand, then the yes/no columns showing which they apply to. There are a couple "parent" brands, thus the duplicates.

Comment: Honestly, if eliminating the join and cycling through records creating a temporary table using INSERT would be a better path, I'm open to that, too.

Comment: So you have a "main" table with names of items, and then 9 columns (one for each brand)? And you have a "brand" table which contains a brand name, and a yes/no column?

Comment: Correct on the main table. Brand table has company names, then same 9 yes/no columns. Not ideal, I know. Inherited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table structure, this query should work:

```
SELECT itemname, 'Brand1' AS brand
FROM maintable
WHERE brand1 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand2'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand2 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand3'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand3 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand4'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand4 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand5'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand5 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand6'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand6 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand7'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand7 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand8'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand8 = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT itemname, 'Brand9'
FROM maintable
WHERE brand9 = 'Y'
```

It uses several UNION ALL statements to ensure all records are displayed.

It displays the brand name in the second column of the result set, if the table's column is set to Y. This will let you show a list of item names and brands in a single result set.

You'll need to rename the itemname column, the maintable, and each of the brand1-9 columns in my query to match your table.

There might be a better way other than 9 statements and a UNION ALL, but this should work.

Does this give you what you need?

Comment: I had to add a LEFT JOIN to get to the brandfullname in the other table, which allowed me to group on just one field "brands" and not each individual brand. 

SELECT tblLiterature.LitNo, tblLiterature.LitDate, tblLiterature.Rev, tblLiterature.LitDescription, tblLiterature.ModelNos, tblLiterature.ChangeDescription, tblLiterature.LitStatus, tblBrands.BrandFullName, tblLiterature.Brand1
FROM tblBrands LEFT JOIN tblLiterature ON (tblBrands.Brand1 = tblLiterature.Brand1)
WHERE (((tblLiterature.LitStatus)="R") AND ((tblLiterature.Brand1) = -1))
UNION ALL

But that helped a lot. Thank you!